# Missing type to str.format() behavior

Tags: python, printing, format

According to the Python docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), when leaving the type out, it defaults to a type of 'g' for floating point arguments.

However,

```
print("{0:.2}".format(14.9))
```

prints "1.5e+01", while

```
print("{0:.2g}".format(14.9))
```

prints "15"

Is this simply an issue of the documentation being incorrect or is there another reason for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [source code](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/py3k/Objects/stringlib/formatter.h?view=markup), this is a documentation bug. The correct description for the behaviour without a floating point specifier is "like 'g', but always with at least one digit after the decimal point".

Answer (score 1):

You linked the documentation of Python 2.7, but you actually used Python 3.x.  In the [documentation of Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), the behaviour is correctly documented.

The Python 2.7 documentation is faulty anyway:

```
>>> "{0:.2}".format(14.9)
'15.0'

>>> "{0:.2g}".format(14.9)
'15'
```